# Importing the entire content of a .txt file into a single cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, import

I have created a .txt file. It contains multiple paragraphs with an empty line between each. Now I select a cell and import the content of my .txt file using the steps:

Data -> Get Data -> From File -> From Txt/CSV -> (selecting the file-location)

I would like the content of the entire .txt file placed into my selected cell and nowhere else. Unfortunately, instead of the desired result, each paragraph goes into a unique cell with an empty cell between.

How can I achieve the outcome that I aim for?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way that might work if there is no quoted text in the file:

Edit the text file to insert a quote `"` character at the beginning of the first paragraph and the end of the last.

After you select the file you will get a preview showing the data in multiple *columns* this time.  Change the Delimiter to "Custom" but leave the custom delimiter box empty.  It should now show everything in one cell.

(I will try to expand this answer later with a method using a [Power Query M formula](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/) which is accessed through the <kbd>Transform Data</kbd> button on the preview window.)

Answer (score 1):

- Hit transform at the bottom of the window
- Then use the M Code below

  - Import the file as a single column
  - Combine the column into a list
  - Save and Load

    - when you do this, the **List** will be saved into a single cell (with `lf` to separate each original row)
    - *apply wordwrap to the cell*

eg:

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\data.csv"),1,"",ExtraValues.Ignore,65001),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    
    comb = Text.Combine(#"Changed Type"[Column1],"#(lf)")
in
    comb
```